# What does param means in c# (not params)

Tags: c#, marshalling

I found the following attribute declaration.

```
     [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
```

what param keyword means in this context and why should we use it ?

Comment: Please post some additional lines associated with the param: statement, i have never seen such a thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`param` is the **Attribute Target**. Quote from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx):

> The list of possible target values is shown in the following table.
>
> ```
>  C#            Visual Basic    Applies to
>
>
>  assembly      Assembly        Entire assembly
>  module        Module          Current assembly module (which is different from a
>                                  Visual Basic Module)
>  field         Not supported   Field in a class or a struct
>  event         Not supported   Event
>  method        Not supported   Method or get and set property accessors
>  param         Not supported   Method parameters or set property accessor parameters
>  property      Not supported   Property 
>  return        Not supported   Return value of a method, property indexer, or
>                                  get property accessor
>  type          Not supported   Struct, class, interface, enum, or delegate
> ```

In your example, the attribute is probably used for a property setter and assigns the attribute to the (implicit) `value` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to marshaling process using MarshalAs attribute where UnmanagedType.LPTStr denotes that it is marshaling as unicode character. The ' 'param' is used as attribute tag. As Heinzi mentioned that in C# above mentioned target values are allowed, here it is used for a property value parameter.